# Update cart in Woocommerce in ajax on page load

Tags: ajax, woocommerce, cart, w3-total-cache

I have the problem. I installed W3 Total Cache to my site with Woocommerce.
Site works much more faster but I have div with cart info about quantity and price at the header of the site. Something like that:

```
<div class="cart">You have total 5 items on 100 $.</div>
```

It's cached by plugin and it's made actual only after adding an item to cart. Div is updating by ajax. I need to make updating Div at the header on page loading.

How can I do it?

Comment: I have did it already.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you better then this might be what you want:

```
<span class="updating_span">  </span>
```

then in your script do something like this

```
$("#profile-group-edit-submit").attr("value", "Saving...");
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: '{{route('update')}}',
            data: $(".form-class").serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
            $(".updating_span").attr("value", "Updated successfully");
            //success(data.message);
            },
            error: function (err, status) {
            $(".updating_span").attr("value", "Update Failed");
            }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I wanted to do something like in your example, but I found better way for me - fragment caching with Transients API.